# Javascript if statement does not meet other condition when the correct number is entered

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm having an issue with my if statement. When I enter a number less than 16 it will still redirect to the lottery website. I'm not sure what I've missed or done wrong in my javascript code so any help is appreciated!

Javascript:

```
const button = document.querySelector(".image-button");
const age = 16;

function checkAge() {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        prompt("What is your age?");
        if (age >= 16) {
            window.location.assign("https://www.national-lottery.co.uk/")
            alert("You are eligible to play");
        } else if (age < 16) {
            alert("You are not eligible to play");
        }
    });
}

checkAge();
```

Html:

```
<body>

<div class="image-container">
     <img src="lotterylogo.png" class="loto-image">
     <div class="image-title">
          <p>Are you eligible to play the national lottery?</p>
     </div>
     <div class="image-button">
          <button>Check</button>
     </div> 
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: You are using ```const age = 16``` that means it is always 16 and therefore ```age>=16``` is always true for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to capture the user input in the `age` variable, and then check that value:

```js
function checkAge() {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var age = prompt("What is your age?");
        if (age >= 16) {
            window.location.assign("https://www.national-lottery.co.uk/")
            alert("You are eligible to play");
        }
        else {
            alert("You are not eligible to play");
        }
    });
}
```